# How to move jquery mobile panel up

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-plugins, responsive-slides

I am developing a mobile responsive page. Which has main page with multiple icons, on tap each icon a result number will display example: if user taps Apple image in bottom section container will show the number of apple category result.  i.e. Total 12 apple category. when user taps to the search results button the entire page should "move up" to show all the 12 apple list.

Generally jquery panel slides left or right side. Similar effect I am looking out on tap a button or link panel should move up as like panel side right  or left.

Please help me if any similar or existing solutions for this

Thanks in Advance and excuse me for the poos English

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're positioning your div as absolute you should try this:

```
$('#pageToMoveUp').animate({top:'-100%'},500); //or any other given values
```

else:

```
$('#pageToMoveUp').animate({margin-top:'-100%'},500); //or any other given values
```

check out [my website](http://www.a-jafari.com) to see the example.

Comment: This is more line overlapping animation effect. Since I ma using jquery mobile for the development and using panel to leverage all other effects. I need any alternate way to achieve push upwards slide effect for page1 panel so that page 2 panel will move from bottom to occupy main screen viewport and then from second page I have a link, on tap that link my 3rd page will come from the right side and page 2 will push out of the left viewport of the screen.

Comment: the alternative is to reduce the height or width and give it the overflow=hidden!